# Relative URLs confuse Google crawler

Tags: url, googlebot

I'm having some odd problems that are apparently being generated by Google crawler. Bing isn't these errors, so it's kind of confusing. The problem seems to be because of relative links.

Google crawler reports this URL as something it found:

```
http://example.com/event_comments/ChupacabraCon/eedit/event_comments/Siege_of_Augusta/event_comments/Genghis_Con_XXXV/91
```

However that isn't a URL thats generated by the site. The one below is:

```
 http://example.com/event_comments/Genghis_Con_XXXV/91
```

I'm puzzled why Bings crawler isn't having a problem when Google is. Do I need to change all of the relative URLs to strict?  Is there another work around?

Comment: Google shouldn't get confused by relative URLs, unless perhaps there are other issues with your page. I see that you've used the `BASE` element (from which relative URLs are based). However, AFAIK this should take an absolute URL, whereas you have specified a root-relative URL `/`.

Comment: @w3d Nicely spotted - see [this](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/base). Seems like a logical explanation/answer to me (maybe should be entered below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, Google shouldn't get confused by relative URLs, unless perhaps there are other issues with your page.

I see that you've used the BASE element:

```
<base href='/'/>
```

The `href` attribute determines the base URL for the page - the URL from which relative URLs are *based*. However, according to the spec this should take an absolute URL, whereas you have specified a root-relative URL `/`. Modern browsers (FF4+ for instance) can cope with root-relative base URLs, however, this behaviour may not be universal and is possibly where Google is tripping up.

The self closing `/` can also be omitted.

```
<base href="http://findgamers.us/event_comments/Genghis_Con_XXXV/91">
```